# How to enable Emoji 2 from iOS6 in iOS5 devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, emoji, emoticons

I've made an Emoji enabling App once, it was incredibly easy:

Get the dictionary from /User/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preferences.plist, and set the BOOL value of the key: "KeyboardEmojiEverywhere" to true.

However, in iOS6 a new set of emoticons were released, named 'Emoji 2' and supposedly they can be unlocked for pre iOS6 devices too, specifically, from iOS5.1. 
But I can't find anywhere if there's another key in the same plist that you should set to TRUE to unlock the new set.

So my question is, can these new Emoji 2 be unlocked using xCode for iOS5.1? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they can't. I created "Emoji 2", I coined the term when the new unicode characters were created in black and white. I made the app wand was first to market and out of no where Apple redesigned all of the new unicode characters in color and my app exploded in popularity. Many knock-offs came very shortly after but my app and the other apps never unlocked the keyboard, they only indexed the unicode characters (some, including mine, allowed users to access them on a "custom" keyboard of sorts via the romaji keyboard and contact editing).
Source: CEO Apps4Life, LLC.

Comment: thanks for answering, I found the answer after a while myself but still thanks for making me even more sure of my found answer :)